# Windows reading a file over network path open a socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, file-io, file-transfer

When you have a network path open in Windows explorer, and you drag it to a local folder does it open a socket? Also, when you use c# FileStream fin = new FileStream(@"//networkpath/file); does that open a socked? my question is this, would it be just as fast to stream a file over a socket manually as it would be to read it over a network using c#'s filestream?

Comment: I think the only note-worthy difference is the amount of work required to achieve the ultimate goal; using `FileStream` allows you to write less code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows file service works over TCP/IP by default (although not necessarily), so typically, there's a socket involved. Yes, there's some overhead from the SMB protocol that Windows uses. However, for files where transfer time matters, the overhead is small compared to the data.

In addition, coming up with your own file sharing protocol without a very good reason is a bad idea. It's a lot of development and debugging work, you have to install the server part somehow, you have to think of security implications (user authentication, etc), firewalls will break it...  Just not worth it.

To gauge the amount of work involved, read the description of the FTP protocol.

Comment: I have been implementing a system where documents are read over a network and processed. I am not trying to reinvent the wheel in file transfer protocols, but I am also trying to solve a problem we have with picking which file needs to be processed. my curiosity was sparked after wondering how practical it would be to have the server send individual pages from the documents as well as which document to process. What would be a better way to do file picking over a network that doesnt use a server/client socket level solution?

Comment: "Which file needs to be processes" and "Individual pages from the documents" are two very distinct problems. The second has no good solution, unless you have a very uniform set of documents (i. e. all of them are Microsoft Word docs).